# File position in Racket

Tags: io, scheme, racket

I am wondering whether there is something in Racket to manipulate the file position in an input port. 
My case is that I need to make the something like file pointer goes back to one position in case I read stuff that I should not have read.

e.g. 
"I am confused." in the file test.txt.
then the file pointer is after confused before . (I guess)
So is there something I can do in the way that next time I read-string, I get "am", rather than "."??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of completion, there is a [`file-position`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/port-buffers.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._file-position%29%29) function that can retrieve the current position or change it.  But you should generally avoid it, since it makes the code work only on ports where you can actually change a position -- and that's not always true.  As Yasir pointed out, for all of the reading functions there is usually a "peek" version that reads something without moving the position, and that's a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Consider [`peek-string`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Byte_and_String_Input.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._peek-string%29%29) for example. It's identical to `read-string`, except that the returned characters are preserved in the port for future reads.

Comment: @jenny If an answer helped you, and you "accept" it, it's an even better way to say thank you to Yasir.